# Enter key detection in Python

Tags: python

I need some help regarding key detection. I am writing a Typing Speed Test in Python. In this test, there is a sample text that I have to replicate and print the time taken and the number of errors I have made. After writing the text, as soon as I press enter, the program should stop and print the result. I am having difficulty in detection of the "Enter" key when it is pressed.

```
import time
import math

print("SPEED TYPING TEST \n")
print("Sample Text : \n")
print("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ")
print("The test will start in 5 seconds \n")
time.sleep(5)
print("Begin!")
start_time = time.time()
user_input = input()
# Press enter here. The timer stops and tell the total time take to write the sample text
end_time = time.time()
print("Total Time taken: ",math.floor(end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: hey you do  you mean you will input a text and it will print the processed time?

Comment: Can you please explain in more details the problem? i just tried your code and it worked fine!

Comment: you don't need to do that, input() returns what the user typed when enter is pressed

Comment: Yeah, I have figured it out. Thanks for all the help!